# How to save certain number of header in a file out of total header in file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hi I have 300 headers but need to save 100-100 headers in a file. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
headers = 'chai_patient_id,alcoholstatus_current_drinker,alcoholstatus_non_drinker...................condition_abnormal_results_of_liver_function_studies'
```

I need to save 1-100 headers in file1.csv, 101-200 headers in file2.csv and 201-300 headers in file3.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

which would let you iterate over chunks of a given size
so if you have your list of headers with `headers.split(',')` you can use it like this:

```
for n, headers_chunk in enumerate(chunks(headers.split(','), 100)):
    with open("file{}.csv".format(n), "w") as output_csv:
        for header in headers_chunk:
            f.write(header + ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
import csv
data = "read your data hear"
headers = "your,headers,are,hear,.......,"
headers = headers.split(",")

with open("somefile.csv",'w') as fp:
    some_headers = headers[:100]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp,fieldnames=some_headers)
    d = {"header1":"valueone"} # prepare your data
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(d)
    
repeat above code for multiple files
```

Answer (score 0):

first split the header into a list of seperated by the comma.
separate the list files and write them to a files

```
   header = header.split(sep=',')
    file1 = header[0:100]
    file2 = header[100:200]
    file3 = header[200:]
    
    with open('file1.txt', 'w') as files:
        files.writelines('%s\n' % head for head in file1)
    
    with open('file2.txt', 'w') as files:
        files.writelines('%s\n' % head for head in file2)
    
    with open('file3.txt', 'w') as files:
        files.writelines('%s\n' % head for head in file3)
```

This is not a DRY code but it does the job